# Displaying std::map in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, tableview, qtableview

I have a some sort of data stored in a std::map and need to display that in a QTableView.
So I've my model class from QAbstractItemModel, but I'm faced with a problem:

The "data" method gives me a QModelIndex that contains the expected row-number of the data-entry. But since I'm using a map and not a vector, I can't randomly access it with the row parameter.
So my idea was to overwrite the "index"-method that generates the QModelIndex object and contain the appropriate hash-key for each object.
But that doesn't make it any easier, since I'd be required to have to get the hash-key by row-number again.
Of course i could iterate through the entire map from begin() to end() to find the n-th row/element, but that would be extremely inefficient.

Do you have any advice how to approprietly display std::map in a QTableView?

```
struct Data {
    ...
};

std::map<int, Data> dataMapping;

QModelIndex index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent );
QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role );
```

Comment: I think iterating through it would be a fine approach if you don't have a huge amount of data. It would also continue to work if you added more data in on the fly.

Comment: std::map has size(), right? So, that is the max row count. You may have N number of columns (key, Data fields). Then, you can implement it using QModelIndex.